# Make row in column cover all area vertically

Tags: flutter

This is the code I have:

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
                 smallBox(),
                 smallBox(),
            ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
            height: 20.h,
        ),
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, 
            children: [
                 smallBox(),
            ],
        ),
   ],
)
```

In this code there are 3 boxes: 1 in right side, 2 in left side. I want the right side box to cover the area vertically

Answer (score 0):

To set the right layout, in flutter you always have to organize all using Rows and Columns.
If I have correctly understood, you want two small boxes horizontally aligned at the left side and a box that occupies all the available vertical space at the left.
The way you do that really depends on what is for you a `smallBox()` and how its constraints are defined. Let's suppose that for you a `smallBox()` corresponds to a flutter `Container()` widget. What you can do is to organize all in a Row parent widget instead of a Column as you have done:

```
Row(
  children:[
    Column(
      childrend: [
        Expanded(),
        Row(
          children:[
            SizedBox(height: <preferredsize>),
            SizedBox(height: <preferredsize>),
          ]
        ),
        Expanded(),
      ],
    ),
    Container
  ],
)
```

Wrapping the `Row` widget between two `Expanded` widget in a `Column` allows for the row to be vertically centered into the column regardless of its size.